# What kinds of student mentorship and supervision merit inclusion on CV?

Tags: cv, supervision, mentoring

An academic can mentor or supervise a student in many different ways, but I'm unclear about what actually merits inclusion on a CV. Some examples that are clear cut to me include:

-dissertation director or committee member

-thesis advisor for masters student

-thesis advisor for senior or honors students at the undergrad level

Then there are other roles that I've occasionally or never seen on a CV and wondering about their acceptability, such as:

-mentor in a professional organization

-supervisor to a student research assistant

-director of an independent study (university   course for which the student receives credit)

-faculty mentor/advisor for a student research project (meaning, the faculty member is not an author, but instead is guiding the student author, or is maybe listed as the advisor on their IRB application)

I work in the U.S. and am in languages and linguistics.

Comment: Personally, I would include all of those, but some people record none of them.  Ask yourself what message you want to send.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - these are not things I would have thought to include before on my CV, but I'm thinking about it now, since I will be working at a teaching-focused college where working with students is an important component for getting tenure. Since it's also an undergrad institution, I already know that I won't be doing any dissertation directing/committee work, and so being able to list some of the other activities might be a good way to showcase my mentoring/supervising experience. I just don't want it to look like padding.

Comment: If the message you want to send is that you work with students, then yes list those things.